# Phonegap build : links to css and JS files in index.html dont' work

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I don't know why but it seems to me that all my links for JS files and css in my index.html doesn't work. The files are not added to my app. (but the config file is parsed well)
It works fine when I built it with visual for WP7...
This is the head of my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>aaaaa</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myJQM.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
    <script src="phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

(I already tried to remove the meta content-type and "format-detection" and I always remove phonegap.js of my zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My folder lib was with a caps ("Lib"), browsers and WP7 emulator are not case sensitive, Android is.
Stupid error but it tooks me a lot of time to find it -_-